What does それだけの○○がある mean?

それだけのかせぎがあるってことはね。

I found this sentence in a book and I can't understand what it means. I did some research and found that それだけの○○がある is a common pattern, but I have no idea what its actual meaning is. I think かせぎ means income or earnings, but I don't know what the rest of the sentence does to that word, can someone explain it to me? Thanks. Edit: Added pic for more context! 

Any more context?

I added the rest of the paragraph. Let me know if you need anything else.

それだけ means either "that much" or "the amount corresponding to that". Here, だけ means "the extent", not "only". For example:

家を建てるにはそれだけのお金が必要です。

You need that much money to build a house.
(when there's a specific amount of money that has been mentioned)
You need a considerable amount of money (corresponding to the cost) to build a house.
(general statement about the significant cost)


In your case, それだけの稼ぎ means "the income corresponding to that (patterned glass)".

おおよ。そりゃあ、一人前だ。それだけの稼ぎがあるってことはね。
Oh yes. Indeed, (you're) a full-fledged adult. Having enough income to afford it means (that).


I see, thank you so much!
